# Android build RP1A.200720.012 T500XXU3BUF2 has wedged @UIThreadTest

Tags: android, android-espresso

Our Samsung Galaxy Tab7 worked for many months. It ran tests from the Android-Studio editor, and from the `adb` command line. Then right around June 2 it requested a software update, and I absentmindedly acknowledged the button.

After it updated, Espresso tests worked, but tests using @UIThreadTest end prematurely with 'Tests Cancelled\n0 passed.'

So we got a new Samsung Galaxy Tab7, and I configured it for development, and it mostly worked correctly. This time, the `adb` fails on random assertions, while when the editor invokes the same tests, they pass.

Then I allowed the tablet to update to the latest build, and the @UIThreadTest problem came back. I will now introduce a third tablet, this time NOT allow it to update, and get back to work.

I am aware that real programmers don't write automated tests, but how do I appeal to Android? The AndroidStudio button "Submit Feedback" is apparently for bugs in AndroidStudio, not Android.

---

We use `import androidx.test.annotation.UiThreadTest;`, which I can't tell if it's deprecated or not. `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'` or `androidx.test:rules:1.3.0`, right?

---

to reproduce the insect, generate a default app (I did the one with one floating button), and make `useAppContext()` look like this:

```
@UiThreadTest
@Test
public void useAppContext() {
    Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    assertEquals("com.example.myapplication", appContext.getPackageName());

    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }  //  here; have a quantum.
}
```

That failed on an updated tablet, and passed on the tablet with the factory-install kernel.

Comment: how do I submit a bug to Android without using the Submit Bug button because it's broken?

Comment: 1) Given that the Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 has had a number of versions, providing the specific model number/OS version would help readers (build numbers only help Samsung engineers). 2) If you can get consistent results on a different make/model device, then you should check for similar issues and file a bug at: https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs

Comment: ya it's a SM-T500. I don't know how to get a more precise model number. I filed a bug report there, but I doubt the engineers who cut that service pack will see it. All they need to do is read the patches for that service pack to find the one that damaged @UIThreadTest. Which nobody uses except me.

Comment: the kernel kooks are currently looking at the problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193342627

Comment: leveling up to Android 33 fixed the bug.

I was told that I could run older versions on newer devices; that seems important for people who write apps for the masses. (We don't care because we are a vertical solution who ships our own tablets with our robots)