# Where is the implementation of UiThreadTest?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I need to rewrite it to debug it, but all I can find searching in the source of Android is this useless stub:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UiThreadTest {
}
```

I want to debug this issue myself, because I have predictably received zero industry support for it:

[Android build RP1A.200720.012 T500XXU3BUF2 has wedged @UIThreadTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168921/android-build-rp1a-200720-012-t500xxu3buf2-has-wedged-uithreadtest)

Comment: "this useless stub" -- that is how you declare annotations in Java, so I am uncertain why you consider it to be a "useless stub". "all I can find searching in the source of Android" -- there seems to be [a lot more than just that one definition](https://cs.android.com/search?q=UiThreadTest&sq=). Off the cuff, my guess is that you would be looking for the references used in `runner`.

Comment: how do I copy the source of UiThreadTest into my own project so I can then debug it and figure out why the real one broke?

Comment: My guess is that you would have to fork the test runner. The problem is not the annotation, but in code that references the annotation.